# Can't login to Ubuntu VM running on ProxMox via Terminal - Permission denied (publickey,password)

Tags: server, permissions, login, password

I have Ubuntu runing as a virtual server under Proxmox.  From within Proxmox I can enter the console, login with my username and password with no problems.

But when I try to login from my Mac Terminal program, I always get this error:

Permission denied (publickey,password).

I am 100% sure that the username and password I am using is correct.  I have even reset it and rebooted the Ubuntu server after resetting, and I deleted the known_hosts file on my Mac, just in case.  Yet still I can't connect.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Mark

Comment: Did you disable public key authentication when you built the VM? You could also try SSH'ing into the Proxmox host and then SSH into the VM from the Proxmox host. It could look like:
Mac --SSH--> Proxmox --SSH--> VM

Comment: Yes, I'm not using public key authatication,  just plain old u/p. And yes I can connect using Proxmox.  Mac - SSH - Proxmox - SSH - VM Works no problem.  But Mac ->SSH-VM does not.  It was working yesterday actually, just not today.

Comment: Trying running the ssh command with the `-vvv` setting and post the output please.

Comment: Hi Fralewhale, thanks for responding.  I have no idea what happened but today it is working.  Do you still want me to run with -vvv again or is there something else I can check to help me understand what the issue was?  Thanks in advance. -Mark